# Bluetooth receiver only shows as Hands-Free AG Audio (Connected Voice)

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, bluetooth, dongle

I have read all the related threads, but didn't find an answer there.

The thing is the device doesn't show the a2dp sink or stereo audio capability anywhere, including Services tab and device manager.

I only get that low quality mono sound when connecting it to Windows 10 PC.

From the phone I can connect and play back stereo sound without any problem.

I'm thinking this has to be a problem with my very old bluetooth usb adapter. Is it possible that this old adapter (I think it's bt 2.0) has a problem with the bluetooth receiver which is bt 5.0?

### Pictures

Services tab from "Devices and Printers"

[image: Services tab from "Devices and Printers"]

Device Manager

[image: Device Manager]

The adapter

[image: The adapter]

The bluetooth receiver which is connected to a speaker and work fine when connected to phone

[image: The bluetooth receiver which is connected to a speaker and work fine when connected to phone]